# prevent going to confirmation page if entries are not correct

Tags: php

I am doing this to learn, got it from examples here and there and, following an online tutorial. What I have not been able to do so far is to prevent it to go to the confirmation.php page if one of the entry is either empty, has numbers (name and lastname) or the email adress is invalid.

If i use `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` I see when thre is an error in the fields but, when action is set to confirmation.php, even if there is an error, it will go with the entered data.

Just for info of my next step, confirmation.php would be a page displaying the info entered with a submit button (to a DB) or an update button if the user made a mistake so he can fix it before sending to db.

Just so you know, I am just starting paying with php so, please, I would appreciate if your answer was not to generic :-)

Thank you

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $lastNameErr = $emailErr = "";
$name = $lastName = $email = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])||(ctype_space($_POST["name"]))) {
    $nameErr = "Prénom Requis";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Lettre seulement"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["lastName"])||(ctype_space($_POST["lastName"]))) {
    $lastNameErr = "Nom Requis";
  } else {
    $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName)) {
      $lastNameErr = "Lettre seulement"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])||(ctype_space($_POST["email"]))) {
    $emailErr = "Adresse courriel requise";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Adresse courriel non valide"; 
    }
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Inscription du participant</h2>
<p><span class="error">* Champ requis.</span></p>
<form method="post" "confirmation.php">
  Pr&eacute;nom: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Nom: <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $lastName;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastNameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Courriel: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you want just by adding the "required" attribute to your input field html element.

Have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

By adding "required" the browser itself will prevent the form to be sent.

Furthermore, for the "email" input, try to change its type to email (`type="email"` which will also add the default browser validation for an email address.
Have a look here for more default validation in form input fields: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: That is a great step towards it has it will prevent from having empty field or a wrong email adress. But, if the field has a white space it will still go to the confirmation page, same if there is a numeric character ( ie: joh4n ) in either the name or lastname. Using

action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"

shows me the error but, if my action is set to confirmation.php I know it does bring up the error but will still go to confirmation.php with Joh4n has the name.

Comment: Try this: make the "submit" button "inactive" by default. And then change its attribute to "active" only after you've done the validation of all the input fields through javascript. In this way you'll have much more granular control.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `action=` inside your `<form>`. It just says `confirmation.php`

Comment: Copy/paste error. It is indeed there in my code :-)